# Why isn't MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP response returning the full html source?

Tags: html, vba

I am wondering why the response property of an MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP object not returning the full html source. It appears it is only returning the "inner html". I can create an IE object and get the "outer html" but that is not too efficient since I have hundreds of search items.

I have the function shown below (with the URL) that assigns the HTML content to a string.

```
Sub test()
    Dim myString As String
    myString = getECICS2("103-90-2") ' myString only contains inner html
End Sub

Public Function getECICS(ByVal casNum As String) As String
  Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  XMLhttp.setTimeouts 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000
  XMLhttp.Open "GET", "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ecics/chemicalsubstance_consultation.jsp?Lang=en&Cas=" & casNum & "&Cus=&CnCode=&EcCode=&UnCode=&Name=&LangNm=en&Inchi=&Characteristic=&sortOrder=1&Expand=true&offset=0&range=25", False
  XMLhttp.send
  If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
    getECICS = XMLhttp.responseText
  Else
    getECICS = ""
  End If
End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get exactly the same result whether I use your method or just "view source" in the browser. You should look at the source - there's a bunch of script at the top, *before* the opening `<html>` tag.

Comment: yes I know however I am not interested in this, the part that I am interested is at the bottom of the page, for example for this particular search it is "0021314-9" but this number does not appear using my method. Interestingly if i go to firefox Inspector > html > copy outer html, the clipboard contains the search results

Comment: How are you testing for the presence of that "0021314-9" ?  If you're using debug.print you should be aware it only displays up to a maximum number of lines. Otherwise - please expand.

Comment: On second look - seems like the page you're looking at is dynamic: the content is added to after the page has loded, so you cannot use an XMLHttp approach to get at the data: you will need to use some kind of browser automation (such as automating IE).

Comment: well initially I had setup a RegEx pattern search on "myString", i was confused because I was not getting any match, so I wrote the content of "myString" into a text file, and simply searched for "0021314-9" with Notepad. Still no hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim has hit the nail on the head. The webpage uses javascript to update the page once the html has been downloaded. This happens automatically in a browser.

If you run the code below it will dump the response into an html file which you can view in Chrome/IE/FF etc

```
Sub test()
    Dim myString As String
    myString = getECICS("103-90-2") ' myString only contains inner html
End Sub

Public Function getECICS(ByVal casNum As String) As String
  Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  XMLhttp.setTimeouts 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000
  XMLhttp.Open "GET", "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/ecics/chemicalsubstance_consultation.jsp?Lang=en&Cas=" & casNum & "&Cus=&CnCode=&EcCode=&UnCode=&Name=&LangNm=en&Inchi=&Characteristic=&sortOrder=1&Expand=true&offset=0&range=25", False
  XMLhttp.send
  If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
    getECICS = XMLhttp.responseText
  Else
    getECICS = ""
  End If
  outputtext (getECICS)
End Function

Function outputtext(text As String)
Dim MyFile As String, fnum As String
        MyFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.html"
        'set and open file for output
        fnum = FreeFile()
        Open MyFile For Output As fnum
        'use Print when you want the string without quotation marks
        Print #fnum, text
        Close #fnum
End Function
```

Unfortunately, the easiest solution is to run your automation in a browser or script enabled   solution to get at the required data.

Many sites now use javascript/AJAX/Login sessions to control the speed and access to resources these days so you cannot always get the desired speed insreases by not using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have  look at the other methods of `XMLHttpRequest`...

`responseText` returns the response body as text

`responseXML` returns the body as a DOM object

I think you are after:  `XMLhttp.response` which returns the whole response.

or maybe: `XMLhttp.responseBody` ?

I'm not *totally* sure on this 'cos I've only used the C++ interface myself.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453379.aspx#methods

Comment: thannks for your response but  I am afraid using XMLhttp.response didnt change anything. I get the same content in the string.

Comment: it does, but it returned something odd, i think Tim Williams might have the answer you cannot use XMLhttp with a dynamic page.